# Can I change something so Angular shows more errors either on Build or at least in Runtime?

Tags: angular

This code works, because the **item** object has **isOk** (boolean) property.

```
<span *ngIf="item.isOk===true"><fa name="fas fa-check"></fa></span>
```

This code does not work, because the **item** object has NO **isCucuBau** (boolean) property.

```
<span *ngIf="item.isCucuBau===true"><fa name="fas fa-check"></fa></span>
```

But my problem is that the 2nd code is not giving any error to me on **ng build --prod**, and it also does not say anything at **runtime**, the browser just doesn't do anything (empty space instead of the checkmark), and there is also zero error in the **Console**.

Is there anything that I can do to get any kind of feedback when compiling, or at least in the browser? Or this is something that Angular is not capable of doing?

If I have a textbox, and I put `[value]="n/a"` then the compiler shows me that there is no variable called **n/a**, and I think this issue above is similar to that.

**Angular CLI:** 12.2.11, 8.2.14

**node -v:** v16.13.0

**npm --version:** 8.1.0

Answer (score 4):

You can enable [`strictTemplates`](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#stricttemplates) in your `angularCompilerOptions` inside `tsconfig[.app].json`.

The [basic mode](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#basic-mode) states to do exactly what you need, ie:

> If you write `<map [city]="user.address.city">`, the compiler verifies
> the following:
>
> - user is a property on the component class
> - user is an object with an address property. <-- Your use case
> - user.address is an object with a city property

Answer (score -1):

Is possible to do that, you can try used safe navigation operator.

from this : **item.isCucuBau===true**

to this: **item?.isCucuBau===true**

Comment: This would only help if there was a runtime error because of a null/undefined access. In this scenario OP wants to know if there is an option for the compiler to warn when attempting to access a property that just does not exist on the given object. In both of your code snippets the outcome will be `undefined === true` which will always evaluate to `false`.